# How kernel efficiently manages so many process context switches and loading page tables again and again for different processes?

Tags: memory-management, kernel, context-switch

How kernel manages efficiently context switch for so many processes. I am specially curious about how large page tables which can be pretty large are switched all the time with switching happening nearly all the time in multiprocessor systems? I am assuming page table for each process is loaded from disk after each context switch.Correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: `I am assuming page table for each process is loaded from disk after each context switch.` - No, page tables needn't to be loaded from the disk all the time. They are stored in the RAM.

Comment: Usually, there is quite a lot of processes running in the system. However, most of them just sleeps (waits for something) for most of the time, so there is no need to switch context to their threads very often.